# How can someone define a data type, and then use it in other file that's included in the same file, right after the data type definition

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor, asn.1

I needed asn1 BER encoder/decoder and found it as a part of "asn1c" compiler (here's the link http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/).

I have no problems compiling the whole thing, using "configure, make, make install" procedure, but it seems impossible to compile it separately.

I'm trying to compile BER encoder/decoder functionality of this package into a static library, in NetBeans. However, I'm having big problems with some "include" nonsenses. Here's an example...

In the asn1parser.h file there's typedef of new type called "asn1c_integer_t"

```
//some preprocessor statements removed to keep this post short...
typedef intmax_t asn1c_integer_t;


#include "asn1p_list.h"
#include "asn1p_oid.h"      /* Object identifiers (OIDs) */
#include "asn1p_ref.h"      /* References to custom types */
etc...
```

However, some of these files that are included in the previous file (asn1p_oid.h, for example) are using the new data type defined in the previous file.

```
#ifndef ASN1_PARSER_OID_H
#define ASN1_PARSER_OID_H

typedef struct asn1p_oid_arc_s {
    asn1c_integer_t number; /* -1 if not yet defined */
    char *name; /* 0 if not defined */
} asn1p_oid_arc_t;
etc...
```

It makes no sense to me, and I keep getting errors like:

> asn1parser.h:32: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘asn1c_integer_t’

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand the issue here but why not try defining the type in a separate file and include this file in all other files that uses it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was sure that "includes" were the cause of the trouble, however, the problem was this line

```
typedef intmax_t asn1c_integer_t;
```

Apparently my version of gcc does not recognize this intmax_t type. I exchanged it for simple "int", and now it works :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `#include "asn1parser.h"` in "some of these files"? Maybe they are also included form elsewhere, and at that point, the name `asn1c_integer_t` is unknown to the compiler.

Comment: yes, I tried including asn1parser.h in the asn1p_oid.h, and commenting out include of the asn1p_oid.h in asn1parser.h (did this for several files actually), but id didn't help :S